# How can I reliably extract a specific string from stdout when line order isn’t known ahead of time?

Tags: shell

The `networksetup -listallhardwareports` command returns the hardware MAC addresses of all network devices in a Mac.

How can I reliably extract `00:0c:29:5b:14:b3` from stdout when line order isn’t known ahead of time (therefore I can’t use `networksetup -listallhardwareports | sed -n 4p | awk '{print $3}'`)?

```sh
Hardware Port: Wi-Fi
Device: en0
Ethernet Address: 00:0c:29:5b:14:b3

Hardware Port: Bluetooth PAN
Device: en3
Ethernet Address: e1:7e:be:a6:0b:12
```

Comment: did you want to extract both mac or only for `en0` ?

Comment: Do you only want `00:0c:29:5b:14:b3` or all MAC addresses? (or just for wifi, or just for bluetooth?)

Comment: @P.... Only for `en0` device.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Only for `en0` Wi-Fi device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports| awk -v RS= '/en0/{print $NF}'
00:0c:29:5b:14:b3
```

Explanation: This `awk` command is converting all multi-line records into single line records. This is done by unsetting(`-v RS=`) awk's default record separator(`RS`). Later matching if any line(or record) is containg `en0` string in it.

Comment: What does `{$1=$1;}` do? Seems pretty useless.

Comment: its not required in this particular case, however, its for converting each record into one line.

Comment: @P.... This is amazing. Would you mind breaking it down a bit to explain how the `awk` arguments work?

Comment: @sunknudsen  Here each multi line record for each eth interface is converted into a single line using `-v RS=`, `$NF` is the mac address, meaning last field of each record. I would suggest to run  this command to see the behavior of `RS being set to blank `networksetup -listallhardwareports| awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different twist that doesn't join lines, but instead just uses a simple flag to indicate that `en0` was found as the second field and then outputs the last field on the next line and exits:

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports | 
awk '$2=="en0" { nextmac=1; next } nextmac==1 {print $NF; exit}'
00:0c:29:5b:14:b3
```

Both approaches are fine, it's just a bit easier for me to wrap my head around processing each record rather than joining them. Six-to-one is a 1/2 dozen to another.

Comment: Thanks for adding to the conversation. I agree the other answer is a mind bender.

Comment: It's actually a slick way to do it, it just groups all 3-lines for each device together as one record (by unsetting `RS` -- record separator) and picks off the last field if `"en0"` is found in that group of lines. The blank line in the file separates the groups.